# Woocommerce Add Checkbox and link to Product Single Page

Tags: woocommerce, product

I am working on **Woocommerce** based site. And I am new to **Woocommerce**. I want to add checkbox and terms & conditions link on product single page.

[image]

How do I add this ???
Do I need to change any file?? or DO I need to use hooks in functions.php ??

Comment: adding link is easy but what about the validation for this checkbox what exactly u want to achieve like u don't want to allow the customer to add the product to cart unless the checkbox is selected ?  did you tried anything  ?

Comment: Ideally *Terms and Conditions* checkbox is placed at Checkout page not in product-single page. It looks strange by adding *Terms and Conditions* checkbox in the Product single page. Not advisable.